# combine c# program and stuff in just 1 program

Tags: c#, setup-deployment

I have pictures, gifs, textfiles, console applications needed by my c# program. They are all in the same directory with my c# program.

If they downloaded my program, it should be in a single package, a single exe file, all the pics are there, all the dependencies, console apps, bat files.

How can I combine everything in one package? So that users will not see all textfiles, gifs, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make them Embedded Resources.  you can set that in the Property window when the resources are selected in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `resources` to embed `images etc` in the assembly. Have a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: if i embeded them, how can i access them?? do i need to edit their locations (file names) in the source code? pls help

Comment: The link that I have provided contains the example of accessing the image at runtime. System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap1 = myProject.Properties.Resources.Image01

Answer (score 1):

You should use the visual studio deployment wizard to make a setup project that will include all the files and will execute your exe while the installation is in progress and when you build your application there will be only one file "exe or msi".For this Go to Projects->setup and Deployment->Setup project and then create one.You can search online or msdn provides very good samples for that as well.

Thanks

Comment: , is it possible to integrate single packaged exe and clickone?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you need to add the content as Resources to your application. If you're using Visual Studio, just right-click your project and select "Add new Item..."

Then in the list, select "Resource File" (file should be something like Resources.resx)

Then in your Solution Explorer, just open the resource file and add your content to it.

To access it in code, just go

```
Bitmap image = Resources.myImage;
```

or

```
string textData = Resources.myTextData;
```

Comment: @tobis,, lets say,, i have this code in my program  string=connect.exe  how can i access it when embdded?

Comment: @Lufthansa: It sounds like you're trying to create an installer file? If that is the case, then take a look at Kunal's answer. I'm not sure if you can embed a Console app in your executable the same way as an embedded image or textual data. A console app is exactly that...a separate app.

Comment: , yes i wanna create installer file,, but also,, i wanna take advantage of ClickOnce technology( u know clickone?)  so if i make revisions in my program, their programs will be updated too.. question is, is installer style supported by clicone?